# Save a Eval as bool without code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I only need this one variable in the front end of the page. I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
<% bool YesNo = Eval("isParent") == "True" ? true : false  %>
```

Data binding doesnt allow me to do this

Does anyone know a way around this?

Thank you for all your answers, Instead of trying to find  bool value, I made the If return as text  true or false and worked my way around that.(with control properties and css classes)

My Solution

```
 Visible='<%#(string)Eval("isParent") == "True"  ? false : true %>'

 class="<%#(string)Eval("isParent") == "True"  ? "LegendHeader" : "" %>"
```

the reason I did it this way is because the data is bound to the specific fields, as Vladimir Sachek mentioned, if you do it the way I wanted to you'll have to loop the data and set variable accordingly

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: The problem is I want a bool variable , but all my attempts to get that variable gives me error **Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.** I only need that on variable

Comment: that's true. Instead of Eval you need to use DataBinder.Eval(), where the first parameter is your container from which you are taking isParent property

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, Instead of trying to find  bool value, I made the If return as text  true or false and worked my way around that.(with control properties and css classes)                                          **Visible='<%#(string)Eval("isParent") == "True"  ? false : true %>'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **DataBinder.Eval** instead and specify the model you are taking the data from

```
<% bool YesNo = DataBinder.Eval(new{isParent = "True"}, "isParent") == "True" ? true : false; %> 
<%= YesNo %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var YesNo = <%= Eval("isParent").ToString() %> == "True"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
<% bool YesNo(Eval("isParent").toString())  %>
```

Where YesNo is a method in your code behind. Like following

```
public bool YesNo(string sIsParent)
{
    if(sIsParent.equals("1")){ return true; } else { return false; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jack said:

> it gives me error Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and
>   Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

You can use `Eval` only inside Repeater, GridView and similar controls. This is because Eval 
uses the current data item to retrieve the requested property (the 'IsParent')